# Django ChartIt Tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

After installing and implementing Django Chartit I get an error message:

```
Exception Type: SyntaxError at /currencypairs/
Exception Value: invalid syntax (chartdata.py, line 109)
```

When I check line 109 in chartdata.py it shows red squiggly lines with the error message `tuple paramater unpacking not supported in Python3`.

```
sort_grp_fn = lambda (tk, td): tuple(chain(str(td['source'].query), 
                                          [td[t] for t in addl_grp_terms]))
```

The same error is on line 117.

```
sort_by_fn = lambda (tk, td): -1*(abs(td[sort_by_term]))
```

Since I have no experience yet with Lambda expressions I do not know how to solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lambdas accept a *tuple* as the only argument, unpacking that tuple into the variables `tk` and `td`. This feature was removed in Python 3 because it clashed with the syntax of a new Python 3 feature, annotations.

You can fix this by giving the lambdas one argument, and using subscription to access the two elements of the tuple:

```
sort_grp_fn = lambda tk_td: tuple(chain(str(tk_td[1]['source'].query), 
                                          [tk_td[1][t] for t in addl_grp_terms]))
```

and

```
sort_by_fn = lambda tk_td: -1*(abs(tk_td[1][sort_by_term]))
```

I replaced `(tk, td)` with `tk_td` and any references to `td` with `tk_td[1]` (both lambdas ignored the `tk` value).

Note that there may be other issues with the package; porting to Python 3 is not always this easy.